# Error when compiling on Ubuntu

Tags: table-of-contents, linux

I have a problem with compiling tex project on Ubuntu. I can compile it on Windows without any error but not on Ubuntu. I tried many different tex editors but still the same error.

The problematic line is in the toc file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\makebox [0.85cm]{I\hfill } Teoretick\IeC {\'a} \IeC {\v c}\IeC {\'a}st}{8}{part.1}
```

and error message:

```
Use of \@makepicbox doesn't match its definition ...C {\'a} \IeC {\v c}\IeC {\'a}st}{8}{part.1}
Use of \@makebox doesn't match its definition ...C {\'a} \IeC {\v c}\IeC {\'a}st}{8}{part.1}
Missing \endcsname inserted ...C {\'a} \IeC {\v c}\IeC {\'a}st}{8}{part.1}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a ...C {\'a} \IeC {\v c}\IeC {\'a}st}{8}{part.1}
```

But on the windows this line in toc file is the same and it works. Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably you use MikTeX on Windows and TeX Live on Ubuntu. Their auxiliary files (like the toc file) are not always compatible. Just delete all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: On Ubuntu I tried TexMaker, TeXworks, TeXstudio but still the same result. On windows I tried TeXstudio and TexWorks and both of them worked perefectly.

Comment: That's not a matter of editors, but of distributions (I mentioned MikTeX and TeX Live).

Comment: Have you tried removing auxiliary files?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: yes I removed all the generated files. I am not able to create MWE because my template is quite big and contains few hundred lines of code. I found the error causing line but I don't understand the error message. Yes it is probably caused by different distributions because the template was created for Windows users and the only solution for me is use the same TEX distribution.

Comment: You may have found the line where the error surfaces, but the error is probably somewhere else. Oh yes, you are able to create an MWE, I believe in you! ;-) Just remove the bottom half of the main text, remove all auxiliary files and check whether the error is still there. If not, remove the other half. Repeat until the code is small enough to be posted.

Comment: If you want to use a template, you still have to know basic knowledge of LaTeX, including preparing a MWE. Unfortunately, many users just dive in and get stuck with complex templates. There is really no need to use a template.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I give up. The template is really large and complex. It has about one thousand lines of code and it is impossible to reduce it. I need to use this template so my only solution is Windows.

Comment: It is really very, very unlikely that even a template is designed so poorly as to require Windows. MikTeX and TeX Live should give the same results, unless a recent update to something means version differences affect things. The point made above was only that the two produce sometimes incompatible auxiliary files. But the solution to that is simply to delete the auxiliary files.